# Anyway to change the Total title from the WooCommerce order received page's order overview

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

Is there a hook to change the Total title from the WooCommerce order received page's order overview? Please see the below image to understand better
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [gettext WordPress filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/gettext/) to "translate" (rename in your case) that string of text.

Your string is inside the thankyou.php WooCommerce template:

```
esc_html_e( 'Total:', 'woocommerce' );
```

Based on [WooCommerce: How to Translate / Rename Any String](https://www.businessbloomer.com/translate-single-string-woocommerce-wordpress/) tutorial, the right code should be the following:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'bbloomer_translate_woocommerce_strings', 9999, 3 );
  
function bbloomer_translate_woocommerce_strings( $translated, $untranslated, $domain ) {
   if ( ! is_admin() && 'woocommerce' === $domain ) {
      switch ( $translated ) {
         case 'Total:':
            $translated = 'Whatever:';
            break;
      }
   }   
   return $translated;
}
```

Comment: Great! Feel free to mark the answer as completed please